# Disassemble instruction set for 8051 microcontroller

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, microcontroller, disassembly, 8051

I have the following hex opcode sequence for a 8051 microcontroller

785679107A247BFD7C347D407E51745568F869F96AFA6BFB6CFC6DFD6EFE

I found this repo that converts hex to instruction sequences https://github.com/anarcheuz/8051-disassembler.

Using that I was able to get the following assembly instructions

```
x00000000:      37 38        MOV 38 (R0,#immed)
0x00000002:     35           ANL A,@R0
0x00000004:     37 39        MOV 39 (R1,#immed)
0x00000006:     31 30 37     JBC 3037 (bit,offset)
0x00000008:     37 41        MOV 41 (R2,#immed)
0x0000000a:     32 34        ADD 34 (A,#immed)
0x0000000c:     37 42        MOV 42 (R3,#immed)
0x0000000e:     46           MOV R5,A
0x00000010:     37 43        MOV 43 (R4,#immed)
0x00000012:     33 34        ADDC 34 (A,#immed)
0x00000014:     37 44        MOV 44 (R5,#immed)
0x00000016:     34 30        JC 30 (offset)
0x00000018:     37 45        MOV 45 (R6,#immed)
0x0000001a:     35 31        ACALL 31 (addr11)
0x0000001c:     37 34        MOV 34 (A,#immed)
0x0000001e:     35 35        ANL 35 (A,direct)
0x00000020:     36           XRL A,R0
0x00000022:     46           MOV R0,A
0x00000024:     36           XRL A,R1
0x00000026:     46           MOV R1,A
0x00000028:     36           XRL A,R2
0x0000002a:     46           MOV R2,A
0x0000002c:     36           XRL A,R3
0x0000002e:     46           MOV R3,A
0x00000030:     36           XRL A,R4
0x00000032:     46           MOV R4,A
0x00000034:     36           XRL A,R5
0x00000036:     46           MOV R5,A
0x00000038:     36           XRL A,R6
0x0000003a:     46           MOV R6,A
```

On wikipedia there's an explanation what the operations mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51, but since I haven't worked with assembly nor microcontrollers before it was difficult to follow.

Does someone know what the workflow is and what the values in the different registers are at the end?

Comment: proper disassembly of a variable length instruction set should be done in execution order not linearly.

Comment: first you need to correctly convert the machine code to something readable (assembly language) then go through instruction by instruction and perform that operation on paper or an instruction set simulator but this task looks like it will be easier by hand.

Comment: if you dont know what the instruction means while you are looking up each opcode in the documentation you can look up the functionality to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier/faster to just do it by hand, just look at an 8051 instruction set reference.

```
78 56  mov r0,#0x56
79 10  mov r1,#0x10
7A 24  mov r2,#0x24
7B FD  mov r3,#0xFD
7C 34  mov r4,#0x34
7D 40  mov r5,#0x40
7E 51  mov r6,#0x51
74 55  A,#0x55
68     XRL A,R0
```

You can spend another five minutes on it and finish the rest.

Comment: (as Peter pointed out this looks to be some strange string of ascii byte values 0x78, 0x56, 0x79, 0x10 and so on).  Im guessing this is a homework assignment (and I did wayy too much work on it for you)

Comment: Oh, that *wasn't* what I'd been pointing out, I hadn't noticed that.  Double ASCII double jeopardy, well spotted.

Comment: Definitely 0x37, 0x38, 0x35, 0x36...was not how to interpret these but 0x78, 0x56, 0x79, etc look plausible.  The OP called them hex opcodes.  This sounds like homework and half the task is interpreting the machine code.  And unless this is how the teacher/book teaches (and the students have had it explained to them every day), this is is as typical: a pretty crappy textbook/class.  if this is just a hexdump sorta tool then this is not necessarily atypical of an output, but how do you know you are not starting mid instruction?  not enough info.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like disassembly of the string of ASCII characters, not the binary values they represent!  Notice that the middle column (the machine code) is all 0x30..46, i.e. ASCII codes for `'0'` to `'F'`.

e.g. the first 2 bytes you disassembled are `37 38`, which are the ASCII codes for `'7'` and `'8'`, but what you want is a single `78` byte.

You need to hex un-dump into binary before feeding it to that disassembler.

Comment: @old_timer: `0x37` is the ASCII code for `'7'`.  Not sure what you mean.

Comment: 785679107A247BFD7C347D407E51745568F869F96AFA6BFB6CFC6DFD6EFE  is not a string of ascii characters when you make bytes out of them is what I thought you meant, sure 0x37 could be considered ascii for '7' if that is what the code is up to.

Comment: ahh I see the middle columns yes that is not the machine code that is something else, ascii...

Comment: @old_timer: added an example to my answer that makes it easier to see the problem.  My earlier description wasn't super clear.

Comment: it was my bad, I misunderstood your comment didnt read it closely enough, the string did look like it might be ascii so I examined it and it was a lot of garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Enters [radare2](https://rada.re/) (or its [rizin](https://rizin.re/) fork, but you'll have to adjust the [binary names](https://book.rizin.re/first_steps/overview.html)).

```
$ rax2 -s 785679107A247BFD7C347D407E51745568F869F96AFA6BFB6CFC6DFD6EFE
xVyz${�|4}@~QtUh�i�j�k�l�m�n�

$ rasm2 -a 8051 -d 785679107A247BFD7C347D407E51745568F869F96AFA6BFB6CFC6DFD6EFE
mov r0, #0x56
mov r1, #0x10
mov r2, #0x24
mov r3, #0xfd
mov r4, #0x34
mov r5, #0x40
mov r6, #0x51
mov a, #0x55
xrl a, r0
mov r0, a
xrl a, r1
mov r1, a
xrl a, r2
mov r2, a
xrl a, r3
mov r3, a
xrl a, r4
mov r4, a
xrl a, r5
mov r5, a
xrl a, r6
mov r6, a
```

As to the workflow and the final register values, given the instructions, pen and paper is a first learning step. It is overkill here, but for larger code, you can turn to emulation (it seems [unicorn](https://www.unicorn-engine.org/) doesn't support 8051, a search engine will let you know of alternatives).